# How can I set the namespace prefix when serializing with lxml.etree.xmlfile()?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I try to write a very big xml file sequentially.
Here is a minimal code example:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

ET.register_namespace('xsl', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform')
with ET.xmlfile('../output/test.xml', encoding='utf-8') as xf:
     xf.write_declaration()
     with xf.element(ET.QName('http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform', 'root')):
         with xf.element('sub'):
             pass
```

I get the follwing output.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <sub>
     </sub>
</ns0:root>
```

I hoped the prefixes would be xsl:..., but instead got the generic ns0:... .
Does anbody know what I need to tweak here?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything you can tweak. It appears that `register_namespace` is ignored when using `xmlfile`.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of testing I found the right solution. One needs to pass the argument `nsmap={tag : namespace}` on the first element, where the namespace is used.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

with ET.xmlfile('../output/test.xml', encoding='utf-8') as xf:
     xf.write_declaration()
     with xf.element(ET.QName('http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform', 'root'),
                     nsmap={'xsl': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'}):
         with xf.element('sub'):
             pass
```

Successive elements with the same namespace are automatically converted from namespace URI to tag notation. However, if you always pass the nsmap argument you would force a namespace entry on every element (`xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`).

Comment: You included `ET.register_namespace('xsl', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform')` also in the answer, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Now it is gone. Thx for noticing.